# C++ Template Classes and Copy Construction

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any way I can construct an new object from the given object if the template parameters of both objects are identical at run-time? For example:

I have a template class with the declaration:

```
template<typename _Type1, typename _Type2> class Object;
```

Next, I have two instantiations of the template:

```
template class Object<char, int>;
template class Object<wchar_t, wint_t>;
```

Now, I want to write a member function such as:

```
template<typename _Type1, typename _Type2>
Object<char, int> Object<_Type1, _Type2>::toCharObject() {
    if(__gnu_cxx::__are_same<_Type1, char>::__value)
        return *this;
    else {
        //Perform some kind of conversion and return an Object<char, int>
    }
}
```

I have tried a couple of techniques, such as using `__gnu_cxx::__enable_if<__gnu_cxx::__are_same<_Type1, char>::__value, _Type1>::__type` in a copy constructor for the `Oject` class, but I keep running into the error:

```
error: conversion from ‘Object<wchar_t, wint_t>’ to non-scalar type ‘Object<char, int>’ requested
```

Is there no way I can do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your template type names are invalid. Underscore followed by capital letter identifiers are **reserved for use by the implementation**. They might clash with names defined by compiler or standard library.

Comment: @jaif: Don't worry much about the typenames. I just picked them arbitrarily for the example. All my code is actually defined in a different namespace, so there should be no clashes.

Comment: Namespaces are not the issue names - like _Type1 are reserved under ALL circumstances (they might be macros, for example), and in this case are not unlikely to be used by the implementation. Or are you saying that what you posted is not the real code that is causing your problem? Well, don't do that either.

Comment: @Neil: Thanks for the advice. I didn't know that. Anyhow, it is real code which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have should work, the problem is that the compiler is doing a type check on the `return *this` part, even if the types aren't equal (hence the compile error). Just use `return (Object<char, int>)(*this);` and you should be fine -- the only time that code will be executed is when the types are the same anyway, so the cast does nothing other than working around the compile error.

Alternatively, you can use template specialisation:

```
template <class _Type1, class _Type2>
Object<char, int> toCharObject(Object<_Type1, _Type2> obj)
{
  // Do conversion and return
}

// Specialisation when types are equal
template <>
Object<char, int> toCharObject(Object<char, int> obj)
{
  return obj;
}
```

This is a free function as you can see. You can do it as a member function, but it's more tricky because you can't specialise individual member function -- you have to specialise the whole class. You can get around that by factoring out the non-specialised code, but that's really ugly, and this works just as well.

Comment: @Peter: You've hit the nail on the head!! I should have thought of template specialization sooner... I've used it in quite a few place already. Duh!!! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Peter: ...but somehow I can't get the casting to work. If I try to cast it, the compiler reports "error: invalid cast".

Comment: Here's what worked though: `return Object<char, int>(*reinterpret_cast<const Object<char, int> *>(this))`